# concatenate strings to create a array variable reference in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$addons_item_1 = array(
               "addon_1" => "65",
               "addon_2" => "55",
               "addon_3" => "60",
               "addon_4" => "80",
               "addon_5" => "75",
               "addon_6" => "75",
               "addon_7" => "30",
               "addon_8" => "20",
               "addon_9" => "25",
               "addon_10" => "25",
               "addon_11" => "25"
     );

$addons_item_2 = array(
                   "addon_1" => "65",
                   "addon_2" => "55",
                   "addon_3" => "60",
                   "addon_4" => "80",
                   "addon_5" => "75",
                   "addon_6" => "75",
                   "addon_7" => "30",
                   "addon_8" => "20",
                   "addon_9" => "25",
                   "addon_10" => "25",
                   "addon_11" => "25"
         );
```

Now from user input I get the following variable:

```
$item = here value will be "item_1" or "item_2"  according to user input
```

now if user has chose item_1 I have to get addons from first array or if user chose item_2 then I will have to get addons from second array.
I can simply do this by using if-else statements from I have a lot array 20-25 so it will be difficult and messsy so I want to do this but its not working:

```
$item = "item_1"; //now I have to fetch addons from first array
```

My code for that

```
 $addons = $addons_'.$item['addon_1']; //suppose I need only one addon
```

But this code is not working

Comment: Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "variable variables"

```
$item = "item_2";
$ary = ${"addons_{$item}"}; // $ary is now $addons_item_2
```

but this is ugly and messy. Much better would be put all addons into an array:

```
$addons = array(
    1 => array(
       "addon_1" => "65",
       "addon_2" => "55",
        etc
    ),
    2 => array(
       "addon_1" => "65",
       "addon_2" => "55",
        etc
     )
);
```

and simply pick what you want by index:

```
$item = 2;
$xyz = $addons[$item]['addon_2'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Please explain why basic concatenation didn't worked?

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
$addons = $addons_'.$item.'['addon_1'];
```